# Drawing knots in the middle of two brakets (knot-package)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a knot in the middle of two brakets. My idea so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
$\left\langle \left\langle {\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2, scale=0.3]\begin{knot} 
\strand (-1.3,1.3) to [out=right, in=right, looseness=2.2] (-1.3,-1.3);
\strand (1.3,1.3) to [out=left, in=left, looseness=2.2] (1.3,-1.3);
\end{knot}
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}\right\rangle\right\rangle $
\end{document}
```

Now I tried to play with the domain from -2 to 2, but it didn't change anything. Perhaps someone can give me hint, how to draw the tikz-picture exactly in the middle of the two brakets?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try to draw the bracket as part of the tikz picture.

Comment: What is your tikz version? I can not find that library on the documentation of 3.0.0

Comment: @Sigur It is part of current TeX Live. I don't think it is part of the TiKZ package itself - it has its own documentation.

Comment: @crf You're right: http://get-software.net/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3/knots_doc.pdf

Comment: Note that the knot is a red herring. You can reproduce just with the circle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `baseline` to adjust the baseline of the TiKZ picture (p 125 of the manual). By default, the bottom of the picture is placed on the baseline. By passing just `baseline`, the `x-axis` (where `y=0`) is aligned with the baseline of surrounding text. By passing `baseline=value`, an adjustment is made which aligns the horizontal line corresponding to `y=value` with the baseline, effectively centring the picture relative to that line. This can be used with an appropriate `value` to effectively centre the picture relative to the maths delimiters.

Originally, I used `-.5ex`. However, thanks to Manuel and egreg for providing the correct value in terms of font dimensions: `\dimexpr-\fontdimen22\textfont2`. This will use the appropriate dimensions from currently active fonts to centre the picture relative to the delimiters --- that is, this method makes direct use of the same information used to typeset mathematical formulae relative to the baseline of text.

A comparison:

[image: baseline variations]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
  \noindent abc   $\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{f(x^{\sqrt[3]{i^x}})} \right\rangle$
  $\left\langle \left\langle{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2, scale=0.3]
        \begin{knot}
          \strand (-1.3,1.3) to [out=right, in=right, looseness=2.2] (-1.3,-1.3);
          \strand (1.3,1.3) to [out=left, in=left, looseness=2.2] (1.3,-1.3);
        \end{knot}
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (2cm);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\right\rangle\right\rangle$
  abc
  $\left\langle \left\langle{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, domain=-2:2, scale=0.3]
        \begin{knot}
          \strand (-1.3,1.3) to [out=right, in=right, looseness=2.2] (-1.3,-1.3);
          \strand (1.3,1.3) to [out=left, in=left, looseness=2.2] (1.3,-1.3);
        \end{knot}
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (2cm);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\right\rangle\right\rangle$
  abc
  $\left\langle \left\langle{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=\dimexpr-\fontdimen22\textfont2, domain=-2:2, scale=0.3]
        \begin{knot}
          \strand (-1.3,1.3) to [out=right, in=right, looseness=2.2] (-1.3,-1.3);
          \strand (1.3,1.3) to [out=left, in=left, looseness=2.2] (1.3,-1.3);
        \end{knot}
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (2cm);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\right\rangle\right\rangle$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The ideal would be some sort of `baseline=-\fontdimen0`, where there's a number instead of the `0`, which I don't remember right now.

Comment: @Manuel Oh, you mean there's a specific font dimension affecting the baseline of maths vs. text which is not just a function of the font size? That would be better!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, yes, the font dimension that sets the height where `\frac{a}{b} - x` aligns the minus and the horizontal bar of the fraction. In any case, it would be something like `-\fontdimen0\textfont` or something like that.

Comment: @Manuel `\fontdimen22\textfont2`, but it can't be used directly in `baseline=-\fontdimen22\textfont2`. Just define a length, say `\fdxxii`, and do `\setlength{\fdxxii}{-\fontdimen22\textfont2}` just before `\begin{tikzpicture}`; then `baseline=\fdxxii` will do.

Comment: @egreg I found it just now in a question/answer of mine: `baseline=\dimexpr-\fontdimen22\textfont2`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `\vcenter` and a constrained `\hbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
Try it like this:
$\left\langle \left\langle \vcenter{\hbox to 1.6cm{\hss\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2, scale=0.3]\begin{knot} 
\strand (-1.3,1.3) to [out=right, in=right, looseness=2.2] (-1.3,-1.3);
\strand (1.3,1.3) to [out=left, in=left, looseness=2.2] (1.3,-1.3);
\end{knot}
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}\hss}}\right\rangle\right\rangle$
\end{document}
```